# Flex 3 toaster notifications

Tags: apache-flex

I've searched a LOT, but dint get the solution to this: Is there a way to display flex notifications in Windows taskbar, ie, the notification should still be visible even if the application s not exactly frontmost in the monitor..There are ways to do this on AIR, or even flex4..but not Flex3??

Answer (score 0):

Flex is my runtime, not FlashPlayer..so I don think I could use flash.display.ToastWindow? As for Flex 4, a library s available for this purpose called ToasterLib..dunno if it displays even when the flex application is not the topmost in the monitor, though..

Comment: Looks like you need your unregistered accounts merged. If you can change your e-mail to be the same as the one when you used when asking, I can do this automatically for you. Please flag this question for moderator attention, select 'other' and let us know you're ready to merge once you have. This will allow you to edit your questions, leave comments under answers you receive / etc.